# Dimension of the dot product - symbolic calculation

Tags: matrix, symbolic

With the following code

```
$Assumptions = {a \[Element] Matrices[{2, 2}]};
Dimensions[{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}.a.{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}]
```

I get as an answer

```
{3}
```

Why the Mathematica does not give the expected

```
{2,2}
```

?

Comment: `Dimensions` works on any expressions not just matrices and vectors. `{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}.a.{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}` has `Head` of `Dot` and the `Dot` expression has `Dimensions` of `{3}`

Comment: Use `TensorDimensions` instead of `Dimensions`.